# Django newbie NoReverse Exception

Tags: python, django

I'm learning Django and trying their official [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial04/)

I'm getting exception.

```
NoReverseMatch at /polls/2/
Reverse for 'vote' with arguments '('',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

This is urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from polls import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
)
```

This is detail.html

```
<h1>{{ poll.question }}</h1>

{% if error_message %}<p><strong>{{ error_message }}</strong></p>{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' poll.id %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{% for choice in poll.choice_set.all %}
    <input type="radio" name="choice" id="choice{{ forloop.counter }}" value="{{ choice.id }}" />
    <label for="choice{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ choice.choice_text }}</label><br />
{% endfor %}
<input type="submit" value="Vote" />
</form>
```

Generic views

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'polls/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'latest_poll_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """Return the last five published polls."""
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte = timezone.now()).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]


class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/detail.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Question.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now())


class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Question
    template_name = 'polls/results.html'

def vote(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=poll_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the poll voting form.
        return render(request, 'polls/detail.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        })
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        # Always return an HttpResponseRedirect after successfully dealing
        # with POST data. This prevents data from being posted twice if a
        # user hits the Back button.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(p.id,)))
```

And my two models.

```
  class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    author_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date < now

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't provide a poll id when you tried to look at the page. A full trace would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the correct version of the tutorial that matches your version of Django.

You are using the model `Question` from the development version of the tutorial, but you linked to and included the template from the Django 1.5 version of the tutorial.

The development version of the tutorial uses the `Question` model, so the template uses `question.id`, not `poll.id`.

```
<form action="{% url 'polls:vote' question.id %}" method="post">
```

You'll avoid other problems if you start the tutorial again and stick to the same version throughout.